# Bug with char* realloc in loop

Tags: c, sockets, loops, segmentation-fault, realloc

I'm trying to dev a little tool in C which includes HTTP Requests, but I have a problem I can't solve because I can't exactly find my error :/

This is a little part of my tool and I think that the function "http_request" has a problem with some HTML response.

Sometimes I have a segfault, sometimes a "free invalid next size" ... I'm thinking that my pointer has not correctly used.

I've try to reproduce the bug with very long string but nothing is happening..

(I think my problem is in the part `/* receive the response */`)

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>


#define BUF_SIZE 256


char *http_request(char *host, int port, char *r_http)
{
    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sockfd;

    /* create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) printf("ERROR opening socket");

    /* lookup the ip address */
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR, no such host");
        return NULL;
    }
    /* fill in the structure */
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    /* connect the socket */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR connecting");
        return NULL;
    }
    /* send the request */
    int sent = 0,total = strlen(r_http), bytes, received;
    do {
        bytes = write(sockfd,r_http+sent,total-sent);
        if (bytes < 0)
            printf("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < total);


    /* receive the response */
    char *response = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUF_SIZE), *tmp_response = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUF_SIZE), rec_data[BUF_SIZE]={0};
    // unsigned int new_size = BUF_SIZE;
    size_t new_size = BUF_SIZE;

    while((bytes = read(sockfd,rec_data,BUF_SIZE)))
    {
        /* Check if error or end of receipt */
        if (bytes < 0 || bytes == 0)
        {
            if(bytes < 0)
                printf("ERROR reading response from socket");
            break;
        }

        /* Process vars */
        if(new_size == BUF_SIZE)
            snprintf(response,(BUF_SIZE+1),"%s",rec_data);
        else {
            tmp_response = realloc(tmp_response,sizeof(char)*strlen(response));
            memset(tmp_response,0,sizeof(tmp_response));
            snprintf(tmp_response,(new_size+1),"%s",response);

            response = realloc(response,sizeof(char)*strlen(tmp_response)+sizeof(char)*strlen(rec_data));
            memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
            snprintf(response,(new_size+1),"%s%s",tmp_response,rec_data);
        }
        new_size+=BUF_SIZE;
        memset(rec_data,0,sizeof(rec_data));
    }
    /* close the socket */
    close(sockfd);

    /* free space */
    free(r_http);
    free(tmp_response);
    // free(response);
    return response;
}


char *http_get(char *host, int port, char *get_request)
{
    char *base_http = "GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n", *r_http = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(base_http)+sizeof(char)*strlen(get_request));

    sprintf(r_http,base_http,get_request);

    return http_request(host,port,r_http);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    char *resp = http_get("127.0.0.1",80,"/test.html");
    printf("Response: |%s|\n",resp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, don't ever reassign to the pointer variable you pass into `realloc`. The `realloc` function can fail and return `NULL`, leading you to lose the pointer.

Comment: Just a wild guess: `realloc(tmp_response,sizeof(char)*strlen(response)` : shouldn't it be `strlen(response) + 1` ?

Comment: You write past the end of the space allocated by `realloc`

Comment: Secondly, you seem to be reading strings. Don't forget that strings in C have an *extra* character for the terminator.

Comment: `memset(tmp_response,0,sizeof(tmp_response));` is a blunder, `sizeof(tmp_response)` is the size of a pointer

Comment: `snprintf(response,(new_size+1), ` is also no good, `new_size+1` is more than the amount of space you allocated. Maybe you meant to give `new_size+1` as the size to `realloc`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so you can just drop it.

Comment: You allocate memory for `tmp_response`and, afaics, never use it before you re-alloc. And the memset blunder M.M. spotted for `tmp_response` is repeated for `response`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Using `sizeof(type) * n` consistently through all malloc calls is not necessarily a bad idea. At any rate, it is a subjective coding style matter, and as such, it is nothing that we need to even comment.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem: Your `realloc` sizes are consistently one off - You forgot that snprintf will need to have space for the 0 byte at the string end (`strlen` will always give you one byte less than you actually need to store the string)

Other (more marginal) problems:

- You let `snprintf` (which is quite an expensive function) do the job of a simple `memcpy`
- I don't really see the purpose for having a secondary buffer `tmp_response` - you could simply use `rec_data` for that. You would also get rid of one `realloc` call in your code.
- Also quite some of the `memset` (which is used with wrong arguments anyhow) is unnecessary - Just copy the string over, there is not much purpose for clearing the buffers to 0 first, as long as you make sure you copy the string end around consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for you attention!

I've try to refactor my code with your adivce but I've some problem..

I've bug with little response I don't have the last char and sometime the response is in double (concat with the response header)

I've replace snprintf by memcpy and strncat, remove tmp buffer, send my var by reference into memset and add 1 byte space allocation for 0x00 at end of string.

If you see any error even small please tell me :)
My memset is correctly used now?

This is my new loop:

```
while((bytes = read(sockfd,rec_data,BUF_SIZE)))
{
    /* Check if error or end of receipt */
    if (bytes < 0 || bytes == 0)
    {
        if(bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        break;
    }

    /* Process vars */
    if(new_size == BUF_SIZE)
    {
        memcpy(response,rec_data,strlen(rec_data)+1);
        response[strlen(response)-1]=0x00;
    }else
    {
        response = realloc(response,new_size+1);
        strncat(response,rec_data,BUF_SIZE);
        memset(&rec_data,0,BUF_SIZE);
    }
    new_size += BUF_SIZE;
}
```